# ICO token vesting if I quit

Tags: employee-stock-options, vesting

I am part of a post-ICO company that awards me tokens as part of compensation. My employment contract only mentions that x amount of tokens would be vested over y years with no cliff/any other vesting schedule info/clauses regarding what happens if I quit. Does the word vesting automatically subsume that vesting would stop when I quit? I am assuming token vesting is similar to RSU vesting.

Comment: That's a legal question. It depends a) on the country your living in and b) on the contract you have with the company.

Comment: You're basically asking us to interpret a clause in your contract without actually seeing that clause or knowing the jurisdiction. At least in the US, even an employment contract doesn't usually change the relationship to other than at will. So your employer can reduce your salary of benefits at any time anyway.